# How to compile a program with static libcurl?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, curl

There is a following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void){
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if(curl == NULL)
    return 0;

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/getAccessAttributes?id=1");

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    return 0;
  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine if you collect it from the dynamic link library:

```
gcc test.c -lcurl -o test
```

Now I want to raise a static program:

```
gcc test.c /tmp/curl/lib/libcurl.a -static -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lm -lz -DCURL_STATICLIB -I/tmp/curl/include -o test
```

He is going with errors:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
>   (.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /tmp/curl/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-netrc.o): In function`Curl_parsenetrc':
>   netrc.c:(.text+0x3c8): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /tmp/curl/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_addrinfo.o): In function `Curl_getaddrinfo_ex':
>   curl_addrinfo.c:(.text+0x60): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

The program works only if you specify a host ip address and not example.com.
Otherwise the program can not resolve the domain name:

```
$ ./test
Error: Couldn't resolve host name
```

How can I solve the problem of name resolution? Thanks!

P.S.
Static libcurl I collected the following method:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.44.0.tar.lzma
tar xf curl-7.44.0.tar.lzma
cd curl-7.44.0
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/tmp/curl --disable-ldap --disable-sspi --without-librtmp --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-smb --without-libidn
make && make install
```

Comment: I don't see how the warnings you post relate to the problem you describe.

Comment: You want to link against the static versions of __all__ libraries or simply with `libcurl`? Also why do you specify it twice (the one from `tmp` and `-lcurl`; you should use `-L` in order to specify library paths: check [ld man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)).After you statically build your application, what's `ldd test` output?

Answer (score 12):

This is how it looks with dynamic libcurl.

```
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcca3aa000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f5536ed6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5536b3e000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f55368d3000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f5536503000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f55362ed000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5537138000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55360e9000)
```

If you want to link only curl statically, do not use -static. Just add libcurl.a as one of the objects files or use -lcurl, you don't need to specify it twice.
After

```
gcc test.c curl-7.44.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.a -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lm -lz -DCURL_STATICLIB -o test
```

you'll get

```
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9a0a7000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f947cc7e000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f947c8ae000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f947c6aa000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f947c3b1000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f947c19b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f947be03000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f947cee9000)
```

-static means that you want link all statically. Then you need all libraries prepared as static and the result will be:

```
$ ldd test
    not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you did not understand me. I have no problem with static compilation. The problem is that in a statically compiled program is not working domain name resolution.

Comment: You mentioned that you get warnings when complied. Have you managed to compile it without warnings? I've tried your code and it works even when statically linked.

Answer (score 9):

I found a way. libcurl must be configured with key "--enable-ares".

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/tmp/curl --disable-ldap --disable-sspi --without-librtmp --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-smb --without-libidn --enable-ares
```

Then the program will feature gethostbyname and will be able to resolve the domain name.

Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: Why does OpenSSL not feature in your command? I thought it would need to