# Can you embed a dll using visual studio?

Tags: c++

I am using libcurl for trading bot written in c++ everything is working perfectly but when I build the solution I see `libcurl.dll` in the `debug` and `release` folders

I there any way to embed this dll inside the executable in the debug or release folders or is there anything like `pyarmor-webui` for c++ compiling

Comment: you could link the static libcurl

Comment: can you explain how to do that

Comment: The point of a DLL is dynamic loading, if you wanted it embedded, use static linking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102613/how-to-compile-a-program-with-static-libcurl. it will differ a bit depending on your compiler and project.  Something is telling your code to access the dll (usually something fed to the linker at compile time).  Remove that and tell linker to link the static library file.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#using-vcpkg-with-cmake)  to that uses cmake does this embed the libcurl.dll file